# What is this line of Rails code doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end
```

Can you help me understand what's happening in the code above? I'm new to Rails/Ruby.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's negation (`!`) operator repeated twice.

Note that only ruby objects evaluating to false (in boolean expression) are `nil` and `false` itself.

Therefore,

1. `some_role` will be true, `!some_role` is false and `!!some_role` is true again.
2. `nil` is false, `!nil` is true and `!!nil` is false.

So, this is a "clever" way to check whether role returned from `find_by_name` is nil or not. (And therefore whether role with such name exists or not)

I guess, I don't have to tell you that doing this is bad for readability. You can always check if result is nil by normal means, like `result.nil?` or `result == nil`.

Comment: Thanks, not sure I get it yet though. How could you rewrite this for readability, for a rails newbie?

Comment: @nobosh I refactored it a bit.

Comment: I was curious how you could rewrite it to be clearer if that makes sense? thxs

Comment: @nobosh Yes, I also added to 'standard' ways to check if object is _nil_ in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is more readable. No need for the 'self' or 'return'. 'present?' is the opposite of 'nil?' so no negation is required.

```
def role?(role)
  roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize).present?
end
```